# The getter 'key' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: key

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am using version
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"**
**I had a problem with the key**
[image]

Comment: can you show the code what you are doing and the output also

Comment: use `?` null safe

Comment: Where do you use it? @JahidulIslam

Comment: In `CategoriesScreen` constructor between two key and as well check you grid part code and more import things please update code instead of image

Answer (score 1):

you can use `?` null safe as :
This is only example how could you use it:

```
child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Consumer<UserProvider>(builder: (context, model, child) {
                final userData = model.userModels;
                return userData == null
                    ? Container()
                    : Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container()
 ])})])
```

for more you can refer [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.
add `null check` to `Key`

Refer null safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) and [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

```
const CategoriesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: Ok but I'm using an old version and I'm not allowed to do that

Comment: if you used old version so no need to declare this line just remove this line